# $PageNumber in Velocity Template for xml generation

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, velocity

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

The above expression i have defined in the velocity template and i was expecting it to write the same in the xml,but it is coming like this

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{]]></textFieldExpression>
```

This jrxml is used to generate the jasper report where it gets replaced by the page number. 
how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V#[[{PAGE_NUMBER}]]#]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Whatever you write inside `#[[` and `]]#` will not be parsed and printed as it is.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#set ($str1="$V{")
#set ($str2="PAGE_NUMBER}")
```

This Trick workedout.

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$str1$str2]]></textFieldExpression>

<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
```